# correr springboot

Tags: netbeans, spring-boot

Spring boot en netbeans

hola, estoy tratando de hacer una app web, para esto necesito abrir spring boot en netbeans pero al intentar ejecutar nuevo proyecto me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mensaje de error:

```
Scanning for projects...  

-----------------------< com.ejemplo:SpringBoot >-----------------------
Building SpringBoot 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli) @ SpringBoot ---
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal Application.java
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:1000)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:947)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:471)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:76)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  1.484 s
Finished at: 2023-05-03T23:30:02-03:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli) on project SpringBoot: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: prueba a darle run as desde clic derecho en el main. asi solo con la foto y eso no tepudo decir muhco mas

Comment: Al darle a run file (no me aparece run as) me salta el mensaje que subí, pero solo cambia y dice esto:

Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal com.ejemplo.SpringBoot.Application 
Command execution failed.

Comment: Hola Manuco, bienvenido, selecciona el titulo de la clase, dale "click" derecho, selecciona "refactor" luego "rename", escoge un nombre nuevo, y "dale gas", el problema (si no estoy equivocado) es que renombraste la clase "a mano", siempre debes usar "refactor" ya que modifica cosas que tu no ves, y que pueden hacer que tu programa falle.